# Pandas DataFrame: list in data?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, data-cleaning

I am trying to encode integer categorical feature birth by

```py
birth_encoded = encode_integer_categorical_feature(birth, "birth", train_ds)
```

where

```py
def encode_integer_categorical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
    # Create a CategoryEncoding for our integer indices
    encoder = CategoryEncoding(output_mode="binary")

    # Prepare a Dataset that only yields our feature
    feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))

    # Learn the space of possible indices
    encoder.adapt(feature_ds)

    # Apply one-hot encoding to our indices
    encoded_feature = encoder(feature)
    return encoded_feature
```

And get the error:

```py
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I am guessing this is because the birth data is not perfectly cleaned?

The data type of birth is int64 but somehow there is a list in there?

So (if this is the issue, which I'm pretty sure it is) i wonder how to check for  elements in a column of a dataframe that is a list? Or, rather, how to filter out all lists in the birth column for inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

With the sample DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': [1, 2, [1, 2], 3, [1, 2, 3]]})
```

this

```
df_lists = df.Col.apply(lambda x: type(x) == list)
lists = [(i, item) for i, item in zip(df.index, df.Col) if type(item) == list]
```

gives you the following output(`print(df_lists)` and `print(lists)`):

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Col, dtype: bool

[(2, [1, 2]), (4, [1, 2, 3])]
```